# Weird output on 10.1" HDMI/USB touchscreen (Waveshare)

Tags: usb, hdmi, touchscreen

I have an HDMI+USB 10.1" screen connected to Pi. When used only HDMI is work fine but when pluged usb (touch) the display weird output.
[image]

Comment: looks like there might be *something wrong™* with it - is there anything in the `dmesg` or other system logs that may point to some software or driver error? - or perhaps it's a power issue (i.e. not enough)

Comment: The monitor has external power supply, the USB is for touch controller so i think this is not the power issue.

Comment: so, of the two things I asked, you answered the second and ignored the first .... dmesg, system logs, anything to indicate some sort of software issue